# Validity of Fitzpatrick's derivation of Lorentz force

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

In *Maxwell's Equations and the Principles of Electromagnetism*, Fitzpatrick first gives the magnetic field of a straight long current-carrying wire as a postulate, then from there he argues that the force experienced by a test wire must come from forces experienced by individual charges in it, thus the force per unit length on this wire becomes
$$\vec F=qnA\vec v\times\vec B$$
Where $n$ is the number density of electrons.

Now the number of electrons per unit length is $nA$, and thus force per unit length on the charge becomes
$$\vec f=q\vec v\times\vec B$$
Now I am not able to understand why Fitzpatrick is calling this force per unit length on the charge, simply as force on the charge. And also how can we assume this result to hold true in general when we derived it from steady-state conditions of Ampere's law?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if $\vec f$ is the (average) force on each electron and $nA$ is the number of electrons per unit length, then $nA \vec f$ is the corresponding force per unit length. Going back the other way, $\vec f = \vec F/nA$.

> And also how can we assume this result to hold true in general when we derived it from steady-state conditions of Ampere's law?

Reasonable question - maybe it doesn't. Maybe the real equation is $\vec f = q\vec v \times (\vec B+\epsilon \frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t})$ where $\epsilon \sim 10^{-100}\ s$. But if we assume that the Lorentz force obtained by Fitzpatrick is correct, the resulting theory of classical electromagnetism works phenomenally well in predicting the results of experiments.

---

One of the things some people find difficult about physics is the amount of detective work that goes into it. There is no way to rigorously derive the Lorentz force other than to begin by postulating something else which is more fundamental or sophisticated (e.g. minimal coupling in the electromagnetic Lagrangian) - which then invites the question of how to derive *that*.

Instead, we make observations (*current-carrying wires feel a force in the presence of a magnetic field and that force is proportional to the current*), postulate a model (*the force on the wire is due to the aggregate force on the moving charged particles*), and then derive the consequences (*the force on an individual charged particle is $\vec f= q\vec v \times \vec B$*). We can then apply the resulting theory to new situations to test its compatibility with experiment, which is the ultimate arbiter of whether the theory is a good one or not. We can also test its compatibility with other theories (e.g. special relativity) to see if any inconsistencies emerge, and if they do then they can be investigated further.

Comment: Very nice answer. I think a related point that beginners in physics find counterintuitive (I did) is that there aren't very many guesses that make sense when you actually take them seriously. You might naively think that there are an infinite number of expressions you could try for $f$, so why focus on the Lorentz force law? But there are really not that many ways to write down an expression for $f$ that (a) explain all observations in the domain of validity and (b) do not contain any extraneous terms that have no effect. Such a thing is quite precious, not typical of a random guess.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you! And I agree. I do think, though, that it's very *important* to make those wrong guesses, and see how they lead you astray. Speaking for myself, I learn best by trying and failing *before* the nice elegant solution is explained to me.

Comment: Yes, I agree! I think sometimes in teaching physics we do a disservice by only showing the final answer in a nicely packaged format as if it is inevitable; maybe it would be interesting to show a few guesses people tried that didn't work.

Comment: $$\vec f$$ is the force on each charge per unit length and not just the force on each charge, just the way $$\vec F$$ is force per unit length on total charge (Sorry for confusing notation, I just copied Fitzpatrick's). Also, we can derive Lorentz Force via relativity as done by Schwartz and Ohanian.

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist Force on each charge per unit length doesn't make sense.  Think of it like this: $\vec F \cdot (1\ \mathrm m)$ is the total force on a $1$ m segment of the wire. $nA\cdot (1 \mathrm m)$ is the number of charged particles in a $1$ m segment of the wire. Therefore, $\big[\vec F \cdot (1\  \mathrm m)\big]/\big[nA\cdot (1\ \mathrm m)\big] = \vec F / nA$ is the average force on **each** of the charged particles in that $1$ m segment of wire.

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist And yes, that's what I said - we can postulate something *else* (in this case, special relativity + Coulomb's law + $\ldots$), but then we may as well ask how to derive special relativity and Coulomb's law. Indeed, one of the possible ways to derive the Lorentz transformations is by examining the transformations which preserve the Maxwell equations!

Comment: @J.Murray I see. I may be off-topic here at least with respect to the original question, but personally, I prefer deriving Lorentz transformations via the most general arguments possible (the kind that Mach gave for example) and using only three other experimental facts (superposition, coulombs law, and charge invariance) to proceed further. But is this view helpful or purely conservative? I am just a student right now so I don't know for myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's an assumption that the charge distributive evenly that it was essentially a continuum mechanics, like when a block fallen into the fluid the force was described by the force per unit area. It somewhat made sense in QM level because essentially the amplitude of the electron cloud was assumed to be continuous, or the so called "force per unit length on the charge, simply as force on the charge".

A slight subtle in the question was the fact that the electric interaction and the magnetic interaction were not really separable, consider the electromagnetic tensor. For example, the electric charge in its own frame should only experience the electric force since it's not moving, but a change of the reference frame might give rise to the magnetic interaction. Thus, the charge $e$ characterized the electromagnetic interaction in the continuous description or in the discrete cases.