# Problem in my low-tech attempt at deriving Lorentz's Transformations

Tags: special-relativity

I recently tried to learn the special theory of relativity (a complete beginner) but I am unable to derive the fundamental Lorentz transforms by myself by using basic ideas of length contraction and time dilation.

I could understand that each observer has their own clocks and scales with which they measure things. If we go into the frame of (inertial) observer $A$ then they are at rest. Suppose we see inertial observer $B$ moving at a constant speed $u$ in this frame. All the scales of $B$ have been contracted by a factor $\gamma=\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}$ in the frame of $A$. Thus whenever $B$ reports a length $x'$ then it is "really" $x/\gamma$ is $A$'s units. Using this I can derive the first Lorentz equation. At time $t$, suppose a point is at $X$-coordinate $x$ w.r.t. $A$. Then $B$ will have moved to $ut$, and so should measure the coordinate of this point as $x-ut$. However, because of the change in scales of $B$, $A$ knows that $B$ would instead report $x'=(x-ut)/\gamma$ (smaller units $\implies$ bigger numerical value).

My main issue is with the derivation of time equation. I understand that there is a $ux/c^2$ term as a correction for distance but I do not understand why. Then I thought that time at a far away place $x$ might be this: light travels at speed $c$ and to know what is happening at a distance $x$ away instantaneously is impossible. There is a delay of $x/c$. So when the time at where we are is $t$, the time there is $t$ but we see events with a delay of $x/c$ therefore, the observed time at a place $x$ away is $t-x/c$ (whatever we see corresponds to this time there). Assuming that both $A$ and $B$ were at $(0,0,0,0)$ in the beginning, time would refer to the time difference of current moment from starting moment. So suppose $B$ measures an event $(x',t')$. The "actual" time at that place must be $t'+x'/c$ and because the clock measures too much, $t'+x'/c=t/\gamma$. This is wrong.

I suspect maybe there is a problem because I am alternating between frames in a confusing manner. I tried similar possibilities including first changing $x$ to $x'$ so that I could reason from the frame of $B$ completely but it only gave the Lorentz transform that $B$ would use to compute time measured by $A$. These others reasonings also give erroneous results. I could find some relevant threads and the following is the most relevant one of them:

> [Derivation of time transformation in Lorentz transformations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/733542/derivation-of-time-transformation-in-lorentz-transformations)

Somehow that person could get the correct transform. However, a more experienced user pointed out that there is a flaw:

> Up till equation (2) your derivation is general; it would work for any (sensical) values of $\Delta x,\Delta t$. After this you take $\Delta x=c\Delta t$. **This means you are restricting yourself to intervals in spacetime which move at the speed of light.** What you have derived should only be expected to work for intervals moving at the speed of light and this becomes clear in the last step ... you go from $\Delta t'=\gamma\left(\Delta t-\frac v c\Delta t\right)$ (3) to $\Delta t'=\gamma\left(\Delta t-\frac {v\Delta x} {c^2}\right)$ (4). You should be able to do this step in reverse ... but you can't because (3) ... only works for paths moving at the speed of light.

I suspect I have made the same mistake. But I do not understand why this is incorrect and what is the proper way to proceed. There is a longer derivation on Wikipedia$^{[1]}$ but it is less intuitive; the benefit being it is much more rigorous and gets the correct result. Some experienced users on the forum also said that if suitably modified, my line of reasoning would work. Could you help me?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations#Time_dilation_and_length_contraction

Comment: A side note: I am trying to learn relativity to gain a better understanding of electromagnetism. While I have heard that there are ways of deriving Lorentz transforms from Maxwell's equations, I think gaining multiple perspectives of anything is always useful. Any general advice is welcomed.